# How to create a new list by finding the ratios of two other lists?

Tags: list-manipulation

Suppose we have two lists:

```
data1 = {{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}}
data2 = {{1, 1456}, {2, 1367}, {3, 2080}, {4, 1998}, {5, 1035}}
```

I'd like to create a new list such that

```
result = {{1, 34/1456}, {2, 54/1367}, {3, 66/2080}, {4, 77/1998}, {5, 92/1035}}
```

So, we only need to divide the second members of each pair; the first members remain unchanged.

Comment: You could use something like `data1[[All, 2]]` to extract the second parts of each pair, divide, and then use `Transpose[]` to reassemble.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the elements appear in order:

```
MapThread[{First[#], Last[#]/Last[#2]} &, {data1, data2}]
```

If the elements may appear out of order (i.e. the first element in `data1` may not correspond to the first element in `data2`):

```
{First[#], Last[#]/Last[#2]} & @@@ GatherBy[Join[data1, data2], First]
```

If they appear in order and you don't care about creating a variable or modifying an existing one:

```
data = data1; (* Creates a copy *)
data[[All, 2]] /= data2[[All, 2]];
```

Or if you want to use rules (this is mostly because we can - it's not necessarily something we should do):

```
ReplaceList[{data1, data2}, {
   {___, {i_, v1_}, ___},
   {___, {i_, v2_}, ___}
   } :> {i, v1/v2}]
```

This rule-based one works if the elements appear out order.

Here's another one:

```
List @@@ Normal[
  Association @@ Rule @@@ data1/Association @@ Rule @@@ data2
  ]
```

This has an object oriented feel to it and is for those that want to learn about `UpValues`:

```
f /: f[i_, j_]/f[i_, k_] := {i, j/k}
f @@@ data1/f @@@ data2
```

Comment: awesome answer, my friend!  There is much usefulness here for me to learn, and many nuances of usage displayed...  Thank you for spending the time to share this with us all.

Comment: @FrancisfromResponseBase Thank you, I’m glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 5):

```
Normal @ First @ Ratios[TimeSeries /@ {data2, data1}]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 17/728}, {2, 54/1367}, {3, 33/1040}, {4, 77/1998}, {5, 4/45}}
> ```

Or define a function:

```
ClearAll[rF]
rF = Normal @* First @* Ratios @* Map[TimeSeries] @* Reverse;

rF @ {data1, data2}
```

[image]

```
Normal@ rF @ {data1, data2}
```

> {{1, 17/728}, {2, 54/1367}, {3, 33/1040}, {4, 77/1998}, {5, 4/45}}

Or use the property `"Path"`:

```
rF[{data1, data2}]["Path"]
```

> ```
>  {{1, 17/728}, {2, 54/1367}, {3, 33/1040}, {4, 77/1998}, {5, 4/45}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

as J.M suggested, you can write

```
Transpose[{data1[[;; , 1]],data1[[;; , 2]] / data2[[;; , 2]]}]
```

updated: removed Thread

Comment: (+1) Or, as a 'just for fun' alternative: `Transpose[{data1.{1,0},data1.{0,1}/data2.{0,1}}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}};

b = {{1, 1456}, {2, 1367}, {3, 2080}, {4, 1998}, {5, 1035}};
```

Using `Merge` and `MapApply (new in 13.1)

```
c = Merge[Ratios] @ MapApply[Rule] @ Join[b, a]
```

<|1 -> {17/728}, 2 -> {54/1367}, 3 -> {33/1040}, 4 -> {77/1998}, 5 -> {4/45}|>

Convert to list

```
KeyValueMap[List] @ c
```

{{1, {17/728}}, {2, {54/1367}}, {3, {33/1040}}, {4, {77/1998}}, {5, {4/45}}}

Answer (score 2):

**Using `SequenceReplace` with `Riffle`:**

For lists with the same length:

```
data1 = {{1, 34}, {2, 54}, {3, 66}, {4, 77}, {5, 92}};
data2 = {{1, 1456}, {2, 1367}, {3, 2080}, {4, 1998}, {5, 1035}};

SequenceReplace[{{a_, b_}, {a_, c_}} :> {a, Defer[b/c]}]@
 Riffle[data1, data2]
```

---

**Using `SequenceReplace` with `Transpose`:**

```
SequenceReplace[{{{a_, b_}, {a_, c_}}} :> {a, Defer[b/c]}]@
 Transpose[{data1, data2}]
```

---

*Result:*

> {{1, 34/1456}, {2, 54/1367}, {3, 66/2080}, {4, 77/1998}, {5, 92/1035}}